# How to use Android Emulator on macOS + React Native with as little Android Studio as possible?

Tags: android, macos, react-native, android-virtual-device, expo

I'm using React Native at work on the latest macOS version, allowing me to easily use Simulator for testing and debugging on iOS.

Now I want to debug and test on Android. I have a personal Android device, but it's hard for me to get the app working on it using Expo (don't have a physical cable on me atm, and security at work makes it hard for tunneling service to work over the same network with our staging build).

I'm trying to get an Android emulator running on macOS. I personally hate Android Studio and would rather not use it. I know that there's `sdkmanager` and the [Android Command Line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/) that Microsoft provides, but I'm not sure how to get started using with those. I'd be using Genymotion if it was free, but it isn't unfortunately.

What do other React Native developers who test and debug on Android do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Of course you must avoid Android Studio when it's not really needed, like in the case of Cordova apps, you are totally right.

To get started with the emulators using the **Android SDK and AVD** (emulators) manager GUI app (not the command line) you must carefully follow these steps:

- Intall Android SDK tools v24 (yes, 24 and not other)
- Update them to SDK tools v27 (manually)
- Download your desired SDK platform and system images from SDK Manager
- Create your emulators and run them from the AVD manager

All these steps are detailed on this guide:
[**Using Android 8 and 9 emulators without Android Studio**](https://www.andreszsogon.com/using-android-8-and-9-emulators-without-android-studio/)

Note that depending on your processor, additional steps are required to enable optimizations like Intel HAXM or Hypervisor, as explained at the bottom of the linked article. I hope this gets you started in the right direction.

PS. there are some methods to connect your Android and iOS device wirelessly without USB cable, but it requires the device connected first to restart adb in tcp port 5555.